# Replace paragraph mark only when is preceded by text with specific font size MS word

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find

I have a MS Word document (2016) containing text with different fonts like this

**Abc.q**

Defq

// `Abc.` has font size = 20 pt and `q` that represents `paragraph mark` has font size=10 pt

// `Def` has font size = 16 pt and `q` (paragraph mark) has font size=10 pt

The `paragraph mark` is equivalent to `carriage return CR (^13)`

Then, how can I replace the `paragraph mark` with `string` but only for the texts that have font size = 20 pt, this is in this case only `Abc.` and result would be **Abc.string** using Advance Find/Replace or VBA?

I tried:

```
Find: ^13 --> with font 10pt
Replace: string
```

But that replaces `paragraph mark` with `string` in all cases. I even tried creating a new style with font = 20.pt and in option **Style for following paragraph** I set **q Normal** (Where `q` represents paragraph mark).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could simply done (without using `Find` method) like this

```
Sub ReplacePara()
Dim Para As Paragraph, Xstr As String, Rng As Range
Xstr = "String to be added"
For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
ln = Para.Range.Characters.Count
    If ln > 1 Then
    If Para.Range.Characters(ln - 1).Font.Size = 20 Then
    Para.Range.Text = Left(Para.Range.Text, ln - 1) & Xstr
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Para.Range.Start, End:=Para.Range.Start + ln - 1 + Len(Xstr))
    Rng.Font.Size = 20
    End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Tested to achieve what I understand as your requirement
Edited to assign a Font size of preceding text (i.e 20) for added string. Font name, Bold, italics etc properties (gathered by `Para.Range.Characters(ln - 1).Font........` to a variable before replacement) could also be assigned to added text in same way.

Comment: @Ahmed_AU Hi @Ahmed. Thanks for your answer. It seems to work .The only thing is that the paragraph mark to be replaced have different font size to the texts. For example `Abc `has size 20 pt and the `para mark` has 10pt but sometimes the `para mark` has size 8.5 pt or something else. The issue is that when `q` is replaced with string, the font size of `Abc` is changed to the font size of the `paragraph mark`. Then how to replace the Paragraph mark without affect the style of the previous text? and hot to assing this `Para.Range.Characters(ln - 1)` to a variable? in order to set more options.

Comment: Edited answer. May please feedback.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, it work this time, thanks so much. I have a final issue, if you have chance. Some lines for what I want to replace the `paragraph mark` with `string` begin with a number of one of more digits. These numbers at the begining have font size = 8pt and I want to preserve the font size of that numbers at the begining. Example: `4 this is a line`,`208 another line` Following your logic I think is like determine the number length to avoid change the format of them, but I don´t know how to do it. Thanks for help

Comment: Answer edited to keep leading digits of replacement string font size to 8

Comment: @AhmedU Hi Ahmed. Thanks for your help. I think the previous code you posted works better. This last doesn't seem to work. The numbers at the beginning of each paragraph are change in their font size to 20.

Comment: Though it worked according my understanding, may i rollback the latest edition?

Comment: @AhmedU I think that even the numbers's size are modified with your previous version, it seems to work better for my goal. Then, the previous version is better. Thank you